# CommandParameter returns null the first time CanExecute runs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I've got the following XAML:

```
 <Button Margin="222,256,102,19" Content="Add Customer" Command="{Binding AddCustomers}">
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="Name" Path="SelectedItem"></Binding>
                    <Binding ElementName="Address" Path="SelectedValue"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
```

**CommandParameter** always returns null the first time **CanExecute** runs. This means that in my ViewModel's **CanExecute** method the parameter(**CustomerInfo**) always returns null the first time the method gets executed which causes exceptions.

```
 private bool CanAddCustomers(object CustomerInfo)
        {
            var CustomerInfoToCheck= (object[])CustomerInfo; // exception here the first time it runs because CustomerInfo is null. The second time this method runs, it returns the values I passed in CommandParameter

            ....
        }
```

The **Convertor** method runs after CanExecute(**CanAddCustomers**) runs the first time and then returns the values I passed in the **CommandParameter**. This DOES NOT happen on other button commands which is weird.. What's the deal with this?

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the command parameter and bind the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` target properties to some source properties of the view model directly? This would be the preferred MVVM way of solving this.

Comment: As a general note, setting the DataContext of individual controls is an indication of poor design. A DataContext should be set for a whole view, i.e. a Window or Page. The CustomerViewModel might be provided by a property of the main view model, and you may then write `Command="{Binding CustomerViewModel.AddCustomers}"`.

Comment: Because both of these ```SelectedItem``` and ```SelectedValue``` are already bound to a listview. When you click an item in the ListView they both show the value of the item.

Comment: Edited my question for better explanation, this problem still happens even if the DataContext is not there